# Define predicate within class

Tags: c++, stl, predicate

I have a class with a method which I would also like to be able to use as a predicate.

```
class MyClass {
  bool ParticleHasAncestor(const Particle &particle, int id) const;

  class AncestorPredicate {
    int mId;
   public:
    AncestorPredicate(int idCode) : mId(idCode) { }
    bool operator()(const Particle &particle) const { return ParticleHasAncestor(particle, mId); }
  };
};
```

However, the compiler complains about not being able to use `ParticleHasAncestor()` without an instance of MyClass. Do I need to use a friend class? Or is there a better solution to this?

I am not using C++11, so cannot use lambda functions.

*Update:* `ParticleHasAncestor()` cannot be made static since it uses members of MyClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Java, in C++ an inner class does not own a pointer to the outer class.

`MyClass::AncestorPredicate`, does not have an instance of `MyClass`, and you cannot invoke a non-static method of `MyClass` without a pointer to an object of that class.

You have two options:

**First**. Make `MyClass::ParticleHasAncestor` a static method of `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass {
    static bool ParticleHasAncestor(const Particle &particle, int id);

    class AncestorPredicate {
        int mId;
    public:
        AncestorPredicate(int idCode) : mId(idCode) { }
        bool operator()(const Particle &particle) const 
        { 
            return MyClass::ParticleHasAncestor(particle, mId);
        }
    };
};
```

**Second**. Create an instance of `MyClass` and pass a pointer to `AncestorPredicate`, so that you can invoke `ParticleHasAncestor` on that object:

```
class MyClass {
    bool ParticleHasAncestor(const Particle &particle, int id) const;

    class AncestorPredicate {
        int mId;
        const MyClass* obj;
    public:
        AncestorPredicate(int idCode, const MyClass* _obj) : mId(idCode), obj( _obj ) { }
        bool operator()(const Particle &particle) const 
        { 
            return obj -> ParticleHasAncestor(particle, mId);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: If I use the second option, can I use the predicate within MyClass thus: 
`electrons.erase(std::remove_if(electrons.begin(), electrons.end(), std::not1(AncestorPredicate(higgs_id, this)())), electrons.end())`

Comment: @DavidHall Yes, you can

Comment: Note: I should not have the additional brackets in the above. So just `AncestorPredicate(higgs_id, this)` without trailing `()`

Answer (score 5):

Make this predicate a static method. But it cannot be `const` then.

Comment: "... but it cannot be `const` then." Not that it needs to. `const` would be meaningless on a `static` member function.

Comment: If `ParticleHasAncestor` was static he could also take the next step and consider using `std::bind2nd` so that he could drop the `AncestorPredicate` helper altogether.

Comment: I can't make `ParticleHasAncestor()` static as it depends on members of MyClass.